# Minimum # of resistors algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to design a simple algorithm that takes a vector of standard resistor values along with an input of a desired resistance value and then goes through series and parallel combinations to figure out the minimum number of standard resistors require to achieve that equivalent resistance doing so by any combination of series and parallel resistors, whichever takes the least.

Anyone got any ideas? If I wanted parallel only or series only it would be a lot easier, but not sure how to combine the two for minimum total number of resistors.

FYI if you don't know total series R = S1 + S2 + ...+ SN and Total parallel R = (1/S1 + 1/S2 + ... + 1/SN)^-1

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm attempting this in matlab so the code could be vectorized. I was also planning on not even taking into consideration the tolerances and just using an input list of 5% resistors only.

Comment: The number of different resistances for n resistors connected in all variations of series and parallel is given by http://oeis.org/A005840. The number is asymptotic to n! * (1-log(2)) / (log(2))^(n+1) -> exponential growth. I would be surprised if there were a sensible way to cut this down, particularly if there isn't much pattern to the input values

Comment: "Standard resistor values" in conjunction with their tolerances are designed to cover the whole positive real line. In other words, any resistance is already within tolerance of a standard resistance value, so you can solve your problem with n=1 resistors. :-)

Comment: Well the other part of the code was going to be a variable input in which you could list the resistor values that the lab is out of stock of and they would be removed from the vector list.

Comment: If that's the case then we can think of it almost like a change-making problem.  I think the approach I suggested in my answer will work. One other issue you may want to consider: there are ways of combining resistors that do not break down to series and parallel, e.g., resistors along the edges of a cube. To truly minimize the number of resistors you should consider those networks too.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object to hold a resistance value, plus two resistances from which it came, plus the operation used to obtain the value from the two previous values (series or parallel).

Use some collection data structure like a Set or an ArrayList to hold resistance objects. Your set S1 initially contains just the resistors you have (networks of 1 resistor). Now create a set S2 which is all combinations (series or parallel) of an element of S1 with an element of S1. S3 is combinations of S1 and S2. S4 is combinations of S1 and S3, *plus* combinations of S2 and S2. Continue until you have a member of Sk which is within tolerance (1%, 5%, or 10%, say) of your target value. The resulting resistance object can be unwrapped one step at a time to find the way it was built up.

One other thing you need to consider is how the tolerances combine. Errors will propagate, so you may need 1% resistors to start in order to achieve the resistance you want at the end to a 5% tolerance, say.

Comment: This algorithm is super-exponential.  Even if your set of resistors is relatively small (e.g. 100), you won't even be able to get to 5-resistor networks on a modern computer in a reasonable amount of time or memory (S5 will have ~10^12 elements).

Comment: If two different combinations give the same result (e.g. `R1 + R2 + R3 = R2 + R3 + R1`), the second won't be stored. In this way, it is a dynamic programming algorithm. If there's a way to put a maximum on the size of resistance that's useful for a particular problem, it would be easier to get running time and space estimates.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a genetic algorithm would be best? I don't know the calculation for the big-O notation for this but it looks exponential: O(cⁿ).

I found this comment on another site's [post](http://www.edn.com/design/components-and-packaging/4421194/Resistor-combinations--How-many-values-using-1kohm-resistors--), it's the number of variations that can be attained with resistors of different values (ie brute force):
Networks with 1 resistors: 1
Networks with 2 resistors: 2
Networks with 3 resistors: 10
Networks with 4 resistors: 68
Networks with 5 resistors: 558
Networks with 6 resistors: 5186
Networks with 7 resistors: 53805

A genetic algorithm would avoid brute force, possibly allowing you to come to an answer much sooner. Unfortunately, it cannot guarantee answers with the minimal amount of resistors. It is likely to find close equivalent resistor values with much less work, and it can be weight so that it favours the fewest possible resistors.

I will keep researching this and post anything else I find.

Comment: Not expontential O because you are bound by the "best result thus far" in your algorithm.  Once you know you can get from A to B in 3 steps, you don't need to check beyond.  This feel quite a bit like a path finding algorithm actually.

Comment: Oh neat, so if a normally exponential O equation can be solved in one step, then what do you call it?

Comment: Probably exponential?  :)